# Logging a snapshot of online users for Django website (postgresql backend, nginx webserver)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, session, nginx

In a Django + postgresql website of mine, I need to publicly show all is online at a point in time (it's a social website). How do I do this? For instance, can there be a way to enumerate all logged in users who hit my nginx webserver in the previous 10 mins? Something like that could work. I'm a beginner and fishing for a viable solution at the moment.

---

Currently to accomplish this, I store sessions to the database, [using an external library](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions) to make sessions enumeratable. This allows me to query how many unique users are online at a point in time.

But this scheme creates a lot of needless DB traffic. As a result, logging and pruning logs has become ineffective. Moreover `pgFouine` shows me that session related DB calls are the biggest performance bottleneck my website currently has.

There's a proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879107/generate-a-list-of-online-users), but it uses the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I'm trying a different approach. I've written a middleware where upon each request, the user's `user_id` is [stored](https://redis.io/commands/ZADD) in a global sorted set. I do this only if they're authenticated, and I use the redis key-value store to ensure everything is blazingly fast.

The solution isn't live yet. I'm going to report more here and give a full answer once I'm done. I'll also consider other answers given here before marking the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use django's [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/) to save the result of the db query to memory. That way you don't need to do the expensive database query for every page render.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def count_current_users():
    users = cache.get('users')
    if users is None:
       # last count has timed out
       users = do_expensive_db_query()
       cache.set('users', users, timeout=500)
    return users
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#basic-usage

You can also use [Template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) and write a custom template tag that only runs the db query if the cache is stale. This will cache the result for 500 seconds.

```
{% cache 500 logged_in_users %}
    {% expensive_query_db_for_logged_in_users %}
{% endcache %}
```

If you want your user count to be more real time, you probably have to bypass django's cache framework, and communicate directly with Redis.
Store each logged in user as a key with a set time to live. Getting a list of currently active keys from Redis would be much cheaper than the equivalent query to a sql database. It can also be implemented with just a few lines of python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django-user-sessions, the [Session model](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions/blob/master/user_sessions/models.py) has a `last_activity` field.

You may be able to do something like:

```
from user_sessions import Session
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)
qs = Session.objects.filter(last_activity__gt=time_threshold)
```

Though, the `django-user-sessions` does not have a database index on that field, which means if you have a very large number of users / sessions, that query may be hard and take a long time. A more complicated answer might involve creating a materialzed view (if you're using postgres) that refreshes via a cron job.